# retrieving the correct "this" in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have built my own object:

```
Main.utilities.pool = function (pool) {
    var counter=0;
    var $form = $(pool);

    return {
        add_pool_field: function(){
            $form.find('#practice_type').change(function() {
                if($(this).find("option:selected").val()){
                    var time = new Date().getTime();
                    var regexp = new RegExp( $(this).find("option:selected").data('id'), 'g');
                    $("#items").append('<li class="colorize">' + '<h1>' + this.increment_counter() + '</h1>' + $(this).find("option:selected").data('fields').replace(regexp, time) + '</li>');
                }
            });
        },
        increment_counter: function(){
            return ++counter;
        },
        init: function() {
            this.add_pool_field();
        }
    }
}
```

I call it as such:

```
var $profile_pool = Main.utilities.pool($('#new_form')).init();
```

The problem is in the change event, this refers to a select field. However, I want to access the increment_counter function of the actual anynomous object that was returned from the pool function. When I try this.increment_counter(), it thinks this is the html select field, and so it blows up. How can I gain access to that object within the context of the function passed to change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just save a reference to `this` in local scope of `add_pool_field()`.

```
    add_pool_field: function(){
        var self = this;
        $form.find('#practice_type').change(function() {
            if($(this).find("option:selected").val()){
                var time = new Date().getTime();
                var regexp = new RegExp( $(this).find("option:selected").data('id'), 'g');
                $("#items").append('<li class="colorize">' + '<h1>' + self.increment_counter() + '</h1>' + $(this).find("option:selected").data('fields').replace(regexp, time) + '</li>');
            }
        });
    },
```

Comment: @Vohuman, that was a typo made in haste.

Comment: Yes, I should have figured this out myself. The anonymous function passed to change creates a closure. This keeps everything in the containing function in scope, and that includes local variables such as self. Hence, self now stores a reference to the object and thus can be used in the anonymous inner function.

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep a reference to the `this` that you want, by declaring it as a variable by your other variables -

```
var t = this;
```

Then within the change function, use `t` where you want to have access to the object's `this`.